# ToDo list React.js: How to move completed items in completed item list container after clicking Toggle button in react.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have one quick question, I want to move toggled item from the pending list to the completed item list when `item.completed === true`. So far, I created two different state arrays (list: [], and donelist: []) and passed the item based on the item.completed. There are a few errors I am facing: First: The item is not removed from the pending list but showed in the completed item list. Second: completed item list creating duplicate items when clicking on the toggle button in completed list.

Objective: when I click on the pending item's toggle button, it should move to the completed item list and vice versa.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Container,
  DoneContainer,
  TaskContainer,
  Input,
  Button,
  FormContainer,
  OrderList,
  Div,
  PendingItem,
  CompltedItem,
  Para
} from "./App.styles.js";
import "./styles.css";
const Item = ({ item, handleToggle, handleDelete, dublicate }) => (
  <OrderList item={item}>
    <Div item={item}>{item.value}</Div>
    <button onClick={() => handleToggle(item)}>Toggle</button>
    <button onClick={() => handleDelete(item)}>Delete</button>
  </OrderList>
);
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    list: [],
    donelist: [],
    inputValue: "",
    dublicate: false
  };

  handleClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  };
  handleDelete = (item) => {
    const newlist = this.state.list.filter((element) => element.id !== item.id);
    this.setState({ list: newlist });
  };
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.handleList(this.state.inputValue);
    this.setState({ inputValue: "" });
  };
  handleToggle = (item) => {
    const newlist = this.state.list.map((element) => {
      if (element.id === item.id) {
        element.completed = !element.completed;
        if (element.completed) {
          this.setState({ donelist: [...this.state.donelist, element] });
        }
      }
      return element;
    });
    this.setState({ list: newlist });
  };

  getDublicate = (value) => {
    return this.state.list.find((item) => item.value === value);
  };
  handleList = (value) => {
    if (this.getDublicate(value)) {
      this.setState({ dublicate: !this.state.dublicate });
    } else {
      const item = { value, id: `${Math.random()}`, completed: false };
      const newList = [...this.state.list, item];
      this.setState({ list: newList });
    }
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.donelist);
    return (
      <Container>
        <FormContainer onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Input onChange={this.handleClick} value={this.state.inputValue} />
          <Button>Click</Button>
        </FormContainer>

        <PendingItem>Pending item list: </PendingItem>
        <TaskContainer>
          <ul>
            {this.state.list.map((element) => (
              <Item
                item={element}
                handleToggle={this.handleToggle}
                handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
              />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </TaskContainer>
        <CompltedItem>Completed item list: </CompltedItem>
        <DoneContainer>
          <ul>
            {this.state.donelist.map((element) => (
              <Item
                item={element}
                handleToggle={this.handleToggle}
                handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
              />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </DoneContainer>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-todo-app-2syu10?file=/src/App.js:0-2841

Comment: Use `filter` method to filter out based on `complete` property

Comment: Sandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/todo-list-fgo4mb?file=/src/App.js